# Defining Sequelize model for existing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Please advise on the following issue. I'd like to use Sequelize to work with existing database.

Stack used:

```
- Node.js v6.10.3
- MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7 running on Google Cloud
- Sequelize 4.7.5
```

MySQL contains 1 table - 'test_table' with columns 'id', 'content', 'status' and holds some data.

I want to define testTable model which would "explain" my MySQL 'test_table' for sequelize, so I run:

```
const connection = new Sequelize("dbName", "user", "pass", {
                                     host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
                                     dialect: mysql
                                 });
const testTable = connection.define('test_table', {
                                      id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
                                           allowNull: false, unique: true, 
                                           primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: 
                                           true},
                                      content: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
                                      status: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
                                   });
```

First surprise I get is that from this moment onwards Node completely ignores existence of 'test_table' and creates its 'analogue' (???).

**`C:\Users\dmitri\Desktop\app>node query.js`**

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_tables` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment UNIQUE , `content` VARCHAR(255), `status` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DAT
ETIME NOT NULL, UNIQUE `test_tables_id_unique` (`id`), PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;


Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `content`, `status`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `test_tables` AS `test_table`;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `test_tables`
```

Now MySQL contains two tables:

```
 - 'test_table' (singular) 
 - 'test_tables' (plural) identical to "test_table" but empty.
```

I am trying to **`SELECT`id`,`content`FROM`test_table`** by executing the following Sequelize code:

```
testTable
    .findAll({attributes: ['id', 'content']})
    .then(result=>{
           console.log(result)
         })
```

Instead of returning contents of 'test_table', node keeps ignoring it:

C:\Users\dmitri\Desktop\app>node query.js
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `content` FROM `test_tables` AS `test_table`;

and returns [].

What may be the reason it voluntarily jumps to query 'test_tables' instead of 'test_table'? Am I completely missing something here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have specified the table name in the options. Delete this new table, add the table name option and re-lift the app.

```
connection.define('test_table', {
  //.... your fields
}, {
  tableName: 'test_table'
});
```

On a side note, I like to have my models named with camelcase. `TestTable`. Same goes for `connection.define('TestTable'...`

EDIT:
As your comments I clarify a couple of things:

- You can/have to specify the table name when defining the model. Look at my example. Specifying the tableName property guarantees the pluralization doesnt screw you over.
- You shouldnt do `sequelize.sync()` (unless you know what it does and you want it). Otherwise you might get problems (like sequelize creating another table because it cant find the one it looks for).
- Defining the models is something you have to do if you want to use sequelize. Otherwise it doesnt make sense and you should use just mysql2. You have to define the models to match the tables in your database.

Comment: How can you get the model's instance of a table that is already in a remote database. Im able to connect to a remote db. But instead of directly using query method to write extensive sql queries, can I use the ORM like functionality to query data from an existing table without defining the model in my node app?

Comment: You define the model for sequelize to know what that model looks like. If you want to just do raw queries, create a sequelize instance connected to that database and then do `sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM yourTable')` and that will return results. But you will not be using any of sequelize advantages, so if you are doing this just use the mysql2 package.

Comment: I thought sequelize must have some kind of shortcut to directly read a database and fetch the structure of the db, so that later on I can directly use various methods of sequelize to access and manipulate data without using raw queries.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280081/how-do-i-use-sequelize-npm-package-to-access-an-existing-table-in-a-remote-herok?noredirect=1#comment547368_280081

Comment: If you want to use sequelize property, then yes you have to define the models to reflect what you have in the database. But as I mentioned, you can skip that and just run raw queries. 
So it depends on the depth of what you want to do.
Make sure you are not calling `sequelize.sync` otherwise that might be troublesome.